# "rm -rf /" VS. "mv -r / /dev/null"

Tags: linux, shell, mv, rm

Might be a stupid question, but what would be the worst for your system ?
(I think both)
But to my opinion mv would be the fastest to "delete" it all.
Am I wrong ? 
(don't wana test aniway ^^ )

Comment: usually I do `mkfs.ext3 /dev/sdx#`  would it be faster than rm/mv ?

Answer (score 12):

I'd go with the first option because `mv -r / /dev/null` won't work:

```
$ mkdir A
$ mv -r A /dev/null 
mv: invalid option -- 'r'
Try 'mv --help' for more information.
$ mv A /dev/null 
mv: cannot overwrite non-directory ‘/dev/null’ with directory ‘A’
```

Not to mention that you can't move a directory like / into a subdirectory under itself.

If this is a serious question, why do you bother unlinking the data? For most purposes you can just recreate the file system.

Comment: even `mv /tmp/xyz /dev/null` gave me `overwrite?` warning; `/tmp/xyz` being a directory.

Answer (score 0):

`dd` is the command you need:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sda
```

Then it is unrecoverable overwritten. 
Remark: You may possibly still recover something with a tool like Spinrite, Steve Gibson claims that it can recover data from overwritten blocks using the rest magnetism of the previous write operation.

Another free CLI tool with a more fancy interface, that does several custom overwriting passes is [DBAN](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dban/)

Comment: i hope the OP is asking for the best command to wreck a havoc on his system out of the two options he has.

Comment: Completely unrecoverable, except for all the data on the disk _after_ the length of the image, which can range from nothing to several tebibytes.

Comment: i have an improvement:
dd if=/dev/random of=/dev/sda

Comment: @jringoot If you want to improve your answer, [edit it](https://superuser.com/posts/655975/edit) rather than posting a comment.

Comment: Not `/dev/random`; that'll be very slow on Linux systems. If your goal is to quickly render the data on a disk unrecoverable without destroying the disk (and you didn't encrypt the whole thing to begin with), your best bet is probably to overwrite it with zeroes: so far, no one's publicly announced the ability to recover data once it's been overwritten even just once (and there is|was a bounty, too). If you've got time after that, you can run more passes on it. If you want the disk filled with random data, use `/dev/urandom`—the randomness doesn't need to be _really cryptographically strong._